# How to ignore requests

Tags: phpstorm, xdebug

I started using debugger for PHP recently and it's working well, but I have one problem. When I open page from Chrome I get notification from PHP Storm "Incomming connection from XDebug"...and I can accept or ignore it, which is ok. Then I can debug. And that's connection for the first page, i.e. index.php

Problem is that on page I'm opening I'm displaying i.e. some images and I'm including some CSS or JS file. For all those files Chrome is making additional requests and for all of them I'm getting also that message "Incomming connection from XDebug". So for every valid request I have to click Ignore about 20 times more...to ignore every other file after first one, containing page source.

I tried adding path to dirs I want to ignore in "Skipped paths" under `Languages & Frameworks -> PHP -> Debug`, but it's not working.

Can it be set somehow? Maybe some obvious ignores - I can't debug i.e. image files.

Comment: Are your images/css/js also served by PHP code? What kind of URLs trigger it? Maybe they are 404 responses? What xdebug log says (what file triggers it)? More info about setup and resources hit is needed.

Comment: 1) In general -- yes, Skipped Paths are meant for that. Let say you have `index.php` and `ajax,php` (which is your JS calls when you are on a page). If you are not interested in debugging `ajax.php` then you can add it to that list there. 2) As you can see it works with files and not URLs (e.g. if `/path/1` and `/path/2` are both handled by `some.php` and you are interested in debugging `/path/2` only .. then it's not yet implemented.

Comment: BTW -- you may also try disabling `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Notifications --> PHP Debugger`